# Search and replace is not respecting my "$1" token

Tags: perl, search, replace

Using bash shell on Ubuntu 14.04.  Trying to do a simple search and replace on every line of a file.  I have tried

```
perl -pi -e "s/.*/DELETE FROM my_object_times where ID = '$1';/g" ids.csv
```

but this leaves me with a file full of

```
DELETE FROM my_object_times where ID = '';
```

and everything I wanted to capture is not inserted at all.  What is a better way to do this search and replace?  I expected the final results to be something like

```
DELETE FROM my_object_times where ID = 'abcdef12341234abcdef';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
sed -i "s/.*/DELETE FROM my_object_times where ID = '&';/" ids.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pi -e "s/.*/DELETE FROM my_object_times where ID = '$1';/g" ids.csv
```

Since the Perl snippet is in double-quotes, the shell will expand `$1` to whatever its current value is (probably empty or unset in your case). You need to escape the dollar sign to prevent that. Also, you don't have a capture group in the pattern of the `s///` operator, so `$1` would not contain anything. (`perl -w` or `use warnings` would warn you about this.)

Either add parenthesis to the pattern, or use `$&`. 
Also, the global replacement doesn't seem to work well with a pattern that can be zero-width, so I'd suggest removing the `g`-flag.

So:

```
perl -w -pe "s/.*/DELETE FROM my_object_times where ID = '\$&';/"
```

(Though `&` is not a valid variable in shell, so `$&` will be left as-is. But in general, the `$` would need to be escaped.)

Usually, putting the Perl code in single-quotes would be better, as the dollar sign is quite common in Perl. But here the single quotes inside the Perl code make that a bit hard. One option is to present them in hex:

```
perl -w -pe 's/.*/DELETE FROM my_object_times where ID = \x27$&\x27;/'
```

Comment: "the global replacement doesn't seem to work well with a pattern that can be zero-width"  What exactly does this mean?  Either it does (and I think it does) or does not work., surely?

Comment: @JonBrave, It gives me more than one match per line: one replacing the contents of the line, and one or two more, hitting zero-length parts around the end of the line (around the newline). This prints more than one `x`: `echo "a" | perl -pe 's/.*/x/g;'`. I didn't stay to find out what exactly happens.

Comment: Wow!  I thought the `.*` would gobble everything it could and would not match another time!  Try also: `echo "a" | perl -pe 's/.*/$&x/g;'`

Comment: `s/.+/x/g` and `s/^.*/x/g` only match once, but `s/.*$/x/g` matches a couple of times, so yeah, it seems to think there's something at the end of the string it didn't look into yet, and since the pattern matches an empty string...

Comment: With `g` modifier, perhaps the `.*` should be `(.|\n)*` ?

Comment: @BowlOfRed, the single-quotes are in the replacement string, they should be there in the output, not quote anything. Otherwise that would be a good idea, though. The usual `'...'\''x'\''...'` doesn't look that nice to my eye either.